# Getting null argument when implementing N-tiers architecture with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I created this simple WebAPI project containing the following library class

- Coordination (ServiceLayer)
- Domain (BusinessLayer)
- Data (DataLayer)
- Dtos (Dtos for webapi)

Basically WebAPI project calls(reference) Dtos, and Coordination. Coordination Calls Domain and Domain call Data.

This is what my structure look like.

[image]

My issues is implementing Dependency Injection using Autofac. I can call the Coordination layer, when i try to call the domain layer this is where it get confused.

This is how I defined my registertype

```
public class AutofacWebapiConfig
    {

        public static IContainer Container;

        public static void Initialize(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            Initialize(config, RegisterServices(new ContainerBuilder()));
        }

        public static void Initialize(HttpConfiguration config, IContainer container)
        {
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            //Register your Web API controllers.  
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(nameof(Coordination)))
              .Where(t => t.Namespace.Contains("Services"))
              .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name));

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(nameof(Domain)))
              .Where(j => j.Namespace.Contains("Domain"))
              .As(j => j.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "I" + j.Name));

            //Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.  
            Container = builder.Build();

            return Container;
        }

    }
```

1. A few issues occurs. First it doesn't know how to find Domain, because in theory WebAPI does not talk to the Domain layer.
2. I did add it as a reference but now i get a null argument error. ServiceType cannot be null.

Nothing that jumps out of me from the service implementation

```
 public class StudentService : IStudentService
    {
        private readonly IStudentDomain studentDomain;
        public StudentService(IStudentDomain _studentDomain)
        {
            this.studentDomain = _studentDomain;
        }

        public async Task<StudentDto> GetStudentByID(string id)
        {
            var test = this.studentDomain.getStudentByID(id);
        }
}
```

And here is my domain implementation

```
    public class StudentDomain : IStudentDomain
    {

        public StudentDomain()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return student
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        StudentEntity IStudentDomain.getStudentByID(string id)
        {
            StudentEntity student = new StudentEntity("dd", "aa", "ddd");
            return student;
        }
    }
```

This is the error I keep getting
[image]

I am sorry my os is french, but its just mean the value is null.
Full stack error

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=La valeur ne peut pas être null.
Nom du paramètre : serviceType
  Source=Autofac
  StackTrace:
   at Autofac.Core.TypedService..ctor(Type serviceType)
   at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`3.<As>b__0(Type t)
   at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`3.<As>b__0(Type t)
   at Autofac.Features.Scanning.ScanningRegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`3.<As>b__0(Type t, IRegistrationBuilder`3 rb)
   at Autofac.Features.Scanning.ScanningRegistrationExtensions.ScanTypes(IEnumerable`1 types, IComponentRegistryBuilder cr, IRegistrationBuilder`3 rb)
   at Autofac.Features.Scanning.ScanningRegistrationExtensions.ScanAssemblies(IEnumerable`1 assemblies, IComponentRegistryBuilder cr, IRegistrationBuilder`3 rb)
   at Autofac.Features.Scanning.ScanningRegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<RegisterAssemblyTypes>b__0(IComponentRegistryBuilder cr)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(IComponentRegistryBuilder componentRegistry, Boolean excludeDefaultModules)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options)
   at CB.WebAPI.App_Start.AutofacWebapiConfig.RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder) in C:\source\repos\CB.WebAPI\CB.WebAPI\App_Start\AutofacWebapiConfig.cs:line 43
   at CB.WebAPI.App_Start.AutofacWebapiConfig.Initialize(HttpConfiguration config) in C:\source\repos\CB.WebAPI\CB.WebAPI\App_Start\AutofacWebapiConfig.cs:line 21
   at CB.WebAPI.App_Start.Bootstrapper.Run() in C:\source\repos\CB.WebAPI\CB.WebAPI\App_Start\Bootstrapper.cs:line 14
   at CB.WebAPI.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in C:\source\repos\CB.WebAPI\CB.WebAPI\Global.asax.cs:line 18
```

Here I am adding the global.asax.cs file. Line 18 is my bootstrapper.run();

```
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            Bootstrapper.Run();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the full exception details (which includes the stack trace of the exception and all the inner exceptions) to your question. (no screenshots, only text) As it currently stands, there is no way anyone can answer your question, because the reason of the failure is unlikely to be in the code you provided. Much more context must be created. Your question also feels like a "how do I debug my code" kind of question, which is unsuited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It would also be good to try to reproduce the problem in a small and new project. Start with an empty project and gradually add code until you stumble on the problem. Then work your way back until you find the reason of the exception.

Comment: I know that I can get it working if I remove builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(nameof(Domain))) but i can't implement my business layer at this point.

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the loading of types where the FirstOrDefault call returns null.

Comment: Based on your comment I did change that second builder.reg... line to this builder.RegisterType<StudentDomain>().As<IStudentDomain>(); this works. however I dont want to defined all my interface from my domain layer individually how can i search for all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is an issue with registering `Domain` because `StudentEntity` does not have corresponding interface and `.As(j => j.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "I" + j.Name))` will fail to find one for it.

If you don't want to manually add all types with interfaces try this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(StudentDomain).Assembly)
          .Where(j => j.Namespace.Contains("Domain"))
          .AsImplementedInterfaces()
```

Possibly you will want/need to distinguish between types with interfaces and without them, you can try next approach:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(StudentDomain).Assembly)
          .Where(j => j.Namespace.Contains("Domain") && j.GetInterfaces().Any())
          .AsImplementedInterfaces()

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(StudentDomain).Assembly)
          .Where(j => j.Namespace.Contains("Domain") && !j.GetInterfaces().Any())
          .AsSelf();
```

P.S.

Also I would recommend to change all `Assembly.Load(nameof(SOME_NAME))` to `typeof(TYPE_NAME).Assembly`, I think it is more readable and obvious.

Comment: When I change load(nameof(type_name)) to typeof(type_name).assembly I get the following error: Domain is a namespace but is used like a type.

Comment: Sorry, use `typeof(StudentDomain)` or any other type in corresponding assembly.